# 502 Server Error after configuring the Load Balancer in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, bitnami, server-error

I am using **WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic**, and one VM Instance running in Google Cloud Compute Engine.
I configured a **free SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt** for my website and also configured the **Certbot Auto-Renewal script**.

I tried using Cloudflare and I was receiving 5xx errors sometimes, mostly 522 timeout error. I stopped using the Cloudflare service, and I tried to configure a **GCP load balancer** for my VM Instance.
I created an **Unmanaged Instance Group** and I configured the HTTP protocol for my backend service with **Cloud CDN Enabled** in the load balancer, and for the Frontend, I configured an HTTP and HTTPS protocol and created a **Google Managed SSL Certificate for the HTTPS protocol** in my load balancer.
(The SSL certificate is **ACTIVE**)

I used this link to configure my load balancer in Google Cloud Platform:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google-templates/how-to/configure-lb-ssl-google-templates/

The problem is that **I have 2 SSL Certificates** and I get 502 Server Error:
*

> "Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and
>   could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds."

*

I don't know how to solve this problem.
I just want to use a very basic and common configuration for my website.

I also want to know why I received a **522 timeout error from Cloudflare** and how to solve it.

I need a quick response and appreciate your answers and help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to follow [1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) to create a HTTPS Load Balancer with the backend service [2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service). Once you create that, you can enable CDN [3](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn#enable).

Regarding the errors, Make sure that your backend instance is healthy and supports HTTP/2 protocol. You can verify this by testing connectivity to the backend instance using HTTP/2.

After you verify that the VM uses the HTTP/2 protocol, make sure your firewall setup allows the health checker and load balancer to pass through.

If there are no problems with the firewall setup, ensure that the load balancer is configured to talk to the correct port on the VM. I will also suggest you to walkthrough [4](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#after_configuring_a_custom_origin_requests_to_custom_origin_failed_with_a_5xx_error) for more steps that you can take to troubleshoot this issue.